# Rails - groupdate gem takes too much time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using the `group_by_minute` feature of the `groupdate` gem. However, this is very slow and my data is very sparse so I don't need to create so many groups anyway.

Is there another way I can use the gem in order to have a better performance on sparse data?
Is there an alternative to this gem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Rails cache and build data use `groupdate` gem once per hour or day. I am using such way in my project.